# Fake account creation prevention on a Laravel website

Tags: php, security, laravel, authentication, spam-prevention

I'm working on a Laravel project I'm building on my own that will require a fake account creation prevention system. I've already read some articles online and for now all the solutions which came to my mind are the following ones. I would like to make a mix of following technics, but not sure about how it's handle on other existing websites.

My website will require a bank account / paypal account, but also social networks to enjoy the experience. My service won't need people to pay to access to it.

I wanted to have a return of experience of people creating solutions like this online and what is the best combo or solution to avoid to maximum fake profiles creation ?

### Email validation

- (+) Easy to implement
- (+) Easy to do for users
- (-) Easy for people to bypass with fake emails or trash mails

### Captcha

- (+) Good to block spam bots
- (+) Easy to implement
- (-) Not working for every time of bots, and not working when people creating manually fake profiles

### Social network link

- (+) Could be a good basis to check user presence on Internet
- (-) Not everyone has a social network account
- (-) The social network account could be a scam also

### SMS validation

- (+) Pretty secure
- (-) Not everyone has a mobile or are whiling to give their mobile
- (-) Some platform already exists to send / receive online SMS to easy to avoid this system

### Bank account / Paypal account

- (+) Hard to fake
- (+) Only people who are whiling to fill that information will do it
- (-) How to check the user is real based on that informations ?
- (-) What if the Paypal account is also a fake ?

### Moderators

- (+) Perfect to control all informations
- (-) Consume time
- (-) Consume money

I also know there is an existing online solution for that, but at the beginning of a project it represents a huge cost : [Detect fake accounts](https://siftscience.com/account-abuse)

What are the solutions you are using right now and what would be adapted to minimize the number of fake profiles on a website ?

Comment: Your question is not asking for technical advice, you know the technical limitations... There is only so much you can do to prevent spam / bots.

Comment: I prefer email validation + captcha. Anything more will just scare users away. Use SMS validation if and only if you offer 2FA over SMS. Do **NOT** go the social network or bank/paypal account route, because that's just creepy. Moderators are fine too.

Comment: Captcha (expecially the google one) + email confirmation is the best IMHO. For people that create fake profiles manually... you cannot do big things.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented for prevent spam email registration in `/register` url.

When I try Google Captcha V2, V3, Mews Captcha, neither of one works for me.

Finally [honeypot](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-honeypot) did the job.

Answer (score 0):

option 1) we are using the invitation CODE scenario that will be generated from the admin side and only that users who have the CODE will be able to sign up the website.

option 2) when generally bots or something are using they were filled all form field so we can just take the Empty Form Field and it will be validating while register new user if value will be filled then its bot or something wrong that way we can prevent it.